# Given a normal subgroup N⊆G, when does G contain a subgroup isomorphic to G/N?

Tags: gr.group-theory

Hi people!

This my first question, here. I don't sure if it has a trivial answer, or not.

Let G a group, N normal subgroup in G. In which cases there is a subgroup in G isomorphic to G/N?

TIA

Comment: A first example that comes to mind: let G be a finitely generated free abelian group. Then N is also finitely generated free. Thus, G/N is free of smaller rank. I don't know of any other examples (but that doesn't mean alot coming from me).

Comment: @Ariyan:  If G=Z and  N= 2Z, then G/N = Z/2Z which doesn't embed into Z.

Comment: You should clarify whether you mean a subgroup of $G$ that
is mapped isomorphically to $G/N$ by the natural quotient
mapping $\pi:G \to G/N$, or simply a subgroup of $G$ that is "abstractly" isomorphic to $G/N$. The notions aren't the same.

Comment: Whoops. I'll just leave the comment though.

Comment: George: hmmmm... My original idea was asked for any subgroup in G that were isomorphic to G/N. I guess it's your meaning of "abstractly" isomorphic.

It could be a subgroup "abstractly" isomorphic to G/N, but no subgroup mapped to G/N via the natural quotient mapping?

Comment: @Ariyan - If you'd like to delete it, I can also delete my comment (assuming I remember to come back here!)

Comment: The title of this question should be made more specific.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you're looking at the case where the isomorphism is induced by the quotient $G \to G/N$ (as per George McNinch's comment), then this should be if and only if the sequence
$$ 0 \to N \to G \to G/N \to 0$$
splits. i.e. there is a section $\sigma : G/N \to G$. This is then seen to be equivalent to $G$ being isomorphic to the semidirect product $N \rtimes G/N$.

Comment: Nice!

Thanks to your message, I just discovered the term "split" (I read it in some elementary intro to Category Theory). Interesting... 

I read a bit more at:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_extension

"Split extensions are very easy to classify..."

The splitting lemma:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma

Semidirect product
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product


Comment: But he said it's another meaning in the comment as well.

Answer (score 8):

You have to be careful! Of course in split extensions it is trivial that $G/N$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $G$.
On the other hand there are examples of extensions
$$1\rightarrow N\rightarrow G\rightarrow G/N\rightarrow 1$$
that are not split but nevertheless there is a subgroup $H\le G$ with $H\cong G/N$.

An example would be the quaternion group that cannot be written as a nontrivial extension. But it contains a normal subgroup of index 2 and a subgroup of order 2.

Unfortunatly I don't see a solution to your problem in general.

Answer (score 3):

A good theorem related to your problem is Schur-Zassenhaus theorem. It states that when the normal subgroup N is a Hall subgroup, namely the order of N and the index of N are coprime, then there exists a complement of N, that is a subgroup H s.t. G=NH and N\cap H={identity}. So H is isomorphic to G/N.